# If I buy minecraft with a mojang account on a computer, do I need to buy it on another computer?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I plan on buying a gaming PC as I expect to be able to get it around a year and I currently have a laptop that I play (a pirated version of) minecraft. I heard that minecraft broke out off of the "cringe culture", which convinced me to finally buy it (for now) and later buy the gaming PC, but...

The thing I'm wondering about is, if I buy minecraft on a laptop, will I be able to avoid the whole buying part when I'll get a gaming PC in the future?

Just want to know if I just need to re-download minecraft and log-in on my mojang account or (in the worst case) re-purchase minecraft and log-in on my mojang account...

Comment: Be aware that you cannot play multiplayer at the same time with 2 of the same account.

Comment: @Quijibo That's not entirely true, you can play on an 'offline' server using the same account if you edit the displayName setting in the launcher_profiles.json

Answer (score 28):

As long as you know your mojang email and password, you should be good.  Just log in to your account on the other computer and download it.

Answer (score 6):

Minecraft is linked to your Mojang account, so if you buy it now, you can later install it on your gaming PC without having to rebuy it. All you need is an active Internet connection and your Mojang account credentials. Generally speaking, if you buy a PC game from an online store and it's linked to an account, you can play that game until either you die, the account service the game is linked to dies or your account gets banned.

Comment: by the phrase "the account service the game is linked to dies", you mean if I don't access my account for a period of time?

Comment: no, i believe he means if the actual authorization service goes down and is no longer being used.

Answer (score 3):

No, you just have to download the launcher again and enter your ID / Mail and login, you can do this manimulation as many times as you want, however only one of these pc can connect to the same server at same time

Answer (score 2):

You Just need to log in to your [Mojang](https://www.mojang.com/) account and download minecraft.