# Playing a friends copy of Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

My friend bought Minecraft but he doesn't use it, so he gave it to me. When I tried to log in and download it, it said that I had to buy it again. How do I get into Minecraft?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I use Minecraft on a different computer than the one I bought it on?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/361127/can-i-use-minecraft-on-a-different-computer-than-the-one-i-bought-it-on)

Comment: @BrunoRodrigues That's a different situation since she's using her account on two  different computers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If I buy minecraft with a mojang account on a computer, do I need to buy it on another computer?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/349178/if-i-buy-minecraft-with-a-mojang-account-on-a-computer-do-i-need-to-buy-it-on-a)

Comment: @Robbie he mentions that his friend doesn't use anymore.

Comment: @BrunoRodrigues The guy in your question is using his own account on two separate devices. This guy seemingly just copied the file from his friends computer without the login info. This question has a different answer than the other question.

Answer (score 1):

Hover over "Games" and click Minecraft and instead of clicking "Get Minecraft" click "TRY IT FREE" it will allow you to download it without paying for it, just make sure you log in (with HIS Username and Password) after it installs and before you launch the game.

Answer (score 1):

Downloading Minecraft is free but you need to pay for the account. If you want to play you would need your friends Username and Password. I would also recommend changing the email associated with the account to your email so if you ever get locked out you can get back in.